# Populating form fields on change of drop down using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate data in my fields depending on the value selected in the drop down box. I have passed the dropdown option select to the javascript function, but having problem in updating the form fields. Please check my code for the error I've committed.

This is my html code:

```
 <div class="form-ui">
      <span class="form-elements reqField">
          <select class="dropdown" onchange="populateData(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,1)">
              <option value="1">Please Select</option>
              <option value="2">Mrs.Jane Smith</option>
              <option value="3">Mr.Junior Smith</option>
          </select>
      </span>

      <span class="form-elements reqField">
           <select id="itle1" class="dropdown">
              <option value="1">Mr.</option>
              <option value="2">Ms.</option>
              <option value="3">Mrs.</option>
           </select>
     </span>

    <span class="form-elements">
          <input id="FirstName1" type="text" class="text" value="" />
    </span>

    <span class="form-elements reqField">
          <input id="LastName1" type="text" class="text" value="" />
    </span>
   </div>
```

And the javascript code:

```
 function populateData(value,person){
    if(value==2){
        $('#Title'+person).value=3;
        $('#FirstName'+person).value="Jane";
        $('#LastName'+person).value="Smith";
    }
   if(value==3){

   }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery uses `val()` to get and set values.

So your js function should be

```
$('#FirstName'+person).val("Jane");
$('#LastName'+person).val("Smith");
```

and not

```
$('#FirstName'+person).value="Jane";
$('#LastName'+person).value="Smith";
```

Also

`<select class="dropdown" onchange="populateData(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,1)">`

should be

`<select class="dropdown" onchange="populateData(this.value,1)">`

Comment: Thank you, but I am not able to check the checkbox and also set the value of the other dropdown('title') field. Could u help me with that

Comment: Well, I dont see any checkbox in your code.Also have you visited the link that i have posted in the comments?

Comment: ya, I checked. Used the same code, but the dropdown value doesn't get updated. I didn't add the checkbox code in here, but I do have a checkbox too.

Comment: I added in the checkbox code in jsbin, it works there but not in my page :( What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

quick answer is that I think you need to use val() not value - can't quite remember how it works with select though

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 1):

HTML ID error here `<select id="itle1" class="dropdown">`
Should be `Title1` not `itle1`

Also I think the javascript should look like this

```
function populateData(value,person){
    if(value==2){
        $('#Title'+person+' option[value="3"]').attr('selected','selected');
        $('#FirstName'+person).val("Jane");
        $('#LastName'+person).val("Smith");
    }
    if(value==3){

    }
}
```

Comment: @Angeline Okay :) I wasn't sure about that

Answer (score 0):

You could use a FORM instead of a DIV, and the attribute `name`, instead of `id`.
They were designed a long time ago to manage forms.

You can use jQuery for that, but everything is already built-in in pure Javascript to handle forms.

```
<form class="form-ui">
  <span class="form-elements reqField">
      <select class="dropdown" onchange="populateData(this)">
          <option value="1">Please Select</option>
          <option value="2">Mrs.Jane Smith</option>
          <option value="3">Mr.Junior Smith</option>
      </select>
  </span>

  <span class="form-elements reqField">
       <select name="title" class="dropdown">
          <option value="1">Mr.</option>
          <option value="2">Ms.</option>
          <option value="3">Mrs.</option>
       </select>
 </span>

<span class="form-elements">
      <input name="FirstName" type="text" class="text" value="" />
</span>

<span class="form-elements reqField">
      <input name="LastName" type="text" class="text" value="" />
</span>
</form>
<script>
    function populateData(sel){
        var form = sel.form,
            value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
        switch(value){
            case '3':
                form.FirstName.value = 'Junior';
                form.LastName.value = 'Smith';
                form.title.value = '1';
            break;
            case '2':
            break;
            default:
        }
    }
</script>
```